# setting system date and time using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

VBA for Office2007 seems to give the possibility to set system date and time with:

`date = variable` and `time = variable`

however, if I try the code:

```
Dim Datum1
Datum1 = #12. Februar 1985#
Date = Datum1
```

I get the error message "Permission denied (Error 70)", which seems to indicate that I have no administrator rights, which is not the case.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: It's a bit complicated. I have a text which should contain revision marks of two different editing stages, however, the revision marks of the 1st editing stage have been prematurely and universally accepted.  WinWord gives the possibilities to combine the revision marks of several authors, but instead of carrying over all revision marks from the 1st editing stage I need only a select few. If it is "virgin" text, I can simply copy and paste them. However, if a certain passage carries already marks from the 2nd editing stage, I would have to emulate the process in sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use DateSerial and TimeSerial. For example:

```
Date = DateSerial(2015, 11, 4)   'For Date changing

Time = TimeSerial(12, 10, 22)    'For Time changing
```

...or you can try to use ShellExecute and Date.

Comment: Thanks, aprados. Your "shell"-suggestion made it clear to me that the problem isn't with VBA, it is with my rights. I am logged in as administrator and I can change the date via system settings, but I can't change the date via command line. That might have to do with the fact that I'm running Windows on a Mac under Parallels. I've been trying your suggestion on a only windows machine and it works perfectly, as does my original code line.